# Joining baseline and time-varying data in R

Tags: r, join, merge

I am trying to merge two datasets in R. One of them contains baseline data for a cohort, and the other contains updated time-varying data for those same people over time. I need to merge the two into a long form dataset with one row for each year, but keep the non-time-varying variables (like sex or race, which don't get updated) the same in each row.

For example, with the datasets below, I would want 10 rows per ID number with `marital_status` and `employment` updated in each row, but `sex` remain fixed for each ID number. This seems like it should be relatively simple, but I can't find a way to merge them without leaving `sex` as `NA` in the years past baseline.

```
baseline <- data.frame(
  ID = c(1:10),
  year = 2000,
  marital_status = (sample(0:1, 10, replace = TRUE)),
  employment = (sample(0:1, 10, replace = TRUE)),
  sex = (sample(c("M","F"), 10, replace = TRUE))
)

head(baseline)

time_varying <- data.frame(
  ID = c(1:10),
  year = rep(2001:2010, 10),
  marital_status = (sample(0:1, 100, replace = TRUE)),
  employment = (sample(0:1, 100, replace = TRUE))
)

head(time_varying)
```

Comment: Not sure what you want as a result exactly, but `merge(baseline[c("ID","sex")], time_varying, by="ID")` maybe? Anything non-time-varying keep from the baseline only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `tidyr::fill()` is what you're looking for. It fills in `NA`s with the last non-`NA` value.

Example:

```r
library(tidyverse)

baseline <- data.frame(
  ID = c(1:10),
  year = 2000,
  marital_status = (sample(0:1, 10, replace = TRUE)),
  employment = (sample(0:1, 10, replace = TRUE)),
  sex = (sample(c("M","F"), 10, replace = TRUE))
)


time_varying <- data.frame(
  ID = c(1:10),
  year = rep(2001:2010, 10),
  marital_status = (sample(0:1, 100, replace = TRUE)),
  employment = (sample(0:1, 100, replace = TRUE))
)

baseline %>%
  bind_rows(time_varying) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  arrange(year) %>%
  fill(sex) 
#> # A tibble: 110 × 5
#> # Groups:   ID [10]
#>       ID  year marital_status employment sex  
#>    <int> <dbl>          <int>      <int> <chr>
#>  1     1  2000              1          0 F    
#>  2     2  2000              0          0 M    
#>  3     3  2000              0          1 F    
#>  4     4  2000              0          0 M    
#>  5     5  2000              0          1 F    
#>  6     6  2000              1          0 F    
#>  7     7  2000              1          0 F    
#>  8     8  2000              1          0 F    
#>  9     9  2000              1          0 M    
#> 10    10  2000              0          1 F    
#> # … with 100 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

EDIT: If you want one row per ID, corresponding to the unique years in `time_varying`, then I'd do:

```r
baseline %>%
  # add any other time-invariant cols in this next line
  select(ID, sex) %>% 
  left_join(time_varying, by = "ID")
#>     ID sex year marital_status employment
#> 1    1   M 2001              0          0
#> 2    1   M 2001              1          0
#> 3    1   M 2001              0          0
#> 4    1   M 2001              1          0
#> 5    1   M 2001              1          1
#> 6    1   M 2001              0          0
#> 7    1   M 2001              1          1
#> 8    1   M 2001              0          1
#> 9    1   M 2001              1          1
#> 10   1   M 2001              0          1
#> 11   2   F 2002              1          0
#> 12   2   F 2002              0          0
#> 13   2   F 2002              1          0
#> 14   2   F 2002              1          1
#> 15   2   F 2002              1          0
#> 16   2   F 2002              1          1
#> 17   2   F 2002              1          1
#> 18   2   F 2002              0          1
#> 19   2   F 2002              1          1
#> 20   2   F 2002              1          1
#> 21   3   M 2003              0          0
#> 22   3   M 2003              1          0
#> 23   3   M 2003              1          0
#> 24   3   M 2003              1          0
#> 25   3   M 2003              1          1
#> 26   3   M 2003              1          0
#> 27   3   M 2003              1          1
#> 28   3   M 2003              1          0
#> 29   3   M 2003              0          1
#> 30   3   M 2003              1          0
#> 31   4   F 2004              1          1
#> 32   4   F 2004              1          0
#> 33   4   F 2004              1          0
#> 34   4   F 2004              0          1
#> 35   4   F 2004              1          0
#> 36   4   F 2004              0          0
#> 37   4   F 2004              1          0
#> 38   4   F 2004              1          1
#> 39   4   F 2004              1          1
#> 40   4   F 2004              1          1
#> 41   5   F 2005              0          0
#> 42   5   F 2005              1          0
#> 43   5   F 2005              1          1
#> 44   5   F 2005              1          1
#> 45   5   F 2005              1          0
#> 46   5   F 2005              1          1
#> 47   5   F 2005              0          1
#> 48   5   F 2005              0          1
#> 49   5   F 2005              1          1
#> 50   5   F 2005              0          0
#> 51   6   F 2006              0          1
#> 52   6   F 2006              1          0
#> 53   6   F 2006              0          0
#> 54   6   F 2006              1          1
#> 55   6   F 2006              0          1
#> 56   6   F 2006              1          1
#> 57   6   F 2006              0          1
#> 58   6   F 2006              1          1
#> 59   6   F 2006              0          1
#> 60   6   F 2006              0          1
#> 61   7   F 2007              1          0
#> 62   7   F 2007              0          1
#> 63   7   F 2007              1          0
#> 64   7   F 2007              1          0
#> 65   7   F 2007              1          1
#> 66   7   F 2007              0          0
#> 67   7   F 2007              0          1
#> 68   7   F 2007              1          0
#> 69   7   F 2007              1          0
#> 70   7   F 2007              1          0
#> 71   8   M 2008              1          1
#> 72   8   M 2008              0          0
#> 73   8   M 2008              0          1
#> 74   8   M 2008              1          0
#> 75   8   M 2008              1          0
#> 76   8   M 2008              1          0
#> 77   8   M 2008              1          1
#> 78   8   M 2008              0          1
#> 79   8   M 2008              1          0
#> 80   8   M 2008              1          0
#> 81   9   F 2009              1          0
#> 82   9   F 2009              0          1
#> 83   9   F 2009              1          1
#> 84   9   F 2009              1          0
#> 85   9   F 2009              1          0
#> 86   9   F 2009              1          1
#> 87   9   F 2009              1          1
#> 88   9   F 2009              0          1
#> 89   9   F 2009              0          0
#> 90   9   F 2009              0          1
#> 91  10   M 2010              0          0
#> 92  10   M 2010              1          0
#> 93  10   M 2010              0          0
#> 94  10   M 2010              0          1
#> 95  10   M 2010              0          0
#> 96  10   M 2010              1          1
#> 97  10   M 2010              0          0
#> 98  10   M 2010              1          1
#> 99  10   M 2010              0          0
#> 100 10   M 2010              0          0
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: OP needs to clarify to be sure, but this gives 11 rows per ID instead of "*I would want 10 rows per ID number*"

Answer (score 1):

Given the data you have, you can bind the rows from `time_varying` with the rows from `baseline` (without `sex`); then (inner or outer) join the `baseline` non-time varying columns (ID, sex), with those bound rows:

```
library(dplyr)

inner_join(
  select(baseline, ID, sex),
  bind_rows(select(baseline,-sex), time_varying)
)
```

(Note: as @thelatemail has commented, if the baseline year is 2000, and the time_varying data is from years 2001 to 2010, then long data will have 11 rows per ID)